# clean OO solution for class structure

Tags: oop

I was wondering what the 'cleanest' object oriented way is to distinguish an object that has 1 extra property.

An example:
Assume you have an award class.
this class has 2 subclasses: individualAward, bandAward.

I would like to distinguish awards in a way that individuals and bands that are active for less than x years to recieve a newcomer award instead of a regular award.

Question:
Where do I implement the newcomer property?
Do i make 2 new classes (with no additional functionality), individualNewcomerAward and bandNewcomerAward? Do i add a field to the Award class like isNewcomerCategory?

I don't know what the OO solution is for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly do not want to introduce a new class for each new attribute, so I would add a property to the parent class. Or add a property `activeSince` and a method `isNewcomer()`.

Answer (score 2):

If every award can be a newcomer award, add the field to the award class. If only some of them can, add it there, and possibly create an interface with the isNewcomer method and add it to the respective award classes.
Implementation may depend on what language you are using.